# Keep vars in select laravel when joining

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting all the info about questions and the user.id. After that I am doing a join to get the info of that user.

The problem is that when I do a join I loose the id of the user, it get replaced for the questions.id.

Is there any way to keep that var?

```
$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id','questions.date', 'questions.id_user', 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
->get()
->skip($saltar)
->take($cantidad)
->toJson();
```

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#389 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(11)
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2020-05-13"
    ["id_user"]=>
    int(11)
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Preguna segundo"
    ["description"]=>
    string(16) "segunda pregunta"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(2) "wd"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(4) "Juna"
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add simply to the select fields, an alias for the ids fields.

For example, when you do

```
$preguntas = Question::select('questions.id','questions.date', 'questions.id_user', 
                              'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id', 
                              'users.first_name', 'users.last_name')
                       ->join('users', 'users.id', 'questions.id_user')
                       ->get()
                       ->skip($saltar)
                       ->take($cantidad)
                       ->toJson();
```

Just add to your ids columns an alias like:

```
Question::select('questions.id AS question_id','questions.date', 'questions.id_user',                             
                 'questions.title', 'questions.description', 'users.id AS user_id', 
                 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name');
```

If you want to keep both the id under their object, you need to not select the column to return, but u need to get the Question model instance, and access to user by the property declared via the relationships how you can found out in the offical wiki:

[Eloquent: Relationships Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)